# Print the HTML and PHP Code in Double or single quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fetch, mpdf

I am Displaying HTML Table which fetch data from database in PHP, and Exporting this in PDF Page... Everything is fine, but when PDF file download, except of values from Mysql it display the php code in table, and the issue is with inverted commas, so how to write the code in inverted commas, that it display values exactly in table except of php code?

**WHEN CLICK ON IT**

```
<a href="file.php" class="export-pdf" data-filename="PDFFILE"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PDF FORMAT</button></a>
```

**Exporting Table in PDF Code "FILE.PHP"**

```
<?php require_once 'components/app.php'; ?>
<?php
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("

<table id='fixed_table' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Union Council</th>
        <th>Village</th>
        <th>Recreational</th>
        <th>Awareness Raising</th>
        <th>Training</th>
        <th>Social Mobilization</th>
        <th>Total Activities</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalDistrictUnique();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalUnionCouncilUnique();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalVillages(); ?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalRecreational();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalAwareness();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalTraining();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalSocial();?></b></td>
      <td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalRecreational() + getTotalAwareness() + getTotalTraining() + getTotalSocial(); ?></td>

      </tr>

      <?php
include('connection.php');
$query ='select * from general';
$run =mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $id=$row[0];
    $createdate=$row[1];
    $createday=$row[2];
    $partnername=$row[3];
    $district=$row[4];
    $unioncouncil=$row[5];
    $village=$row[6];
    $vannumber=$row[7];
    $facilitator=$row[8];
    $beneficiarytype=$row[9];
    $rmultimedia=$row[10];
    $rgame=$row[11];
    $rsprort=$row[12];
    $rart=$row[13];
    $rgroupreading=$row[14];
    $rother=$row[15];
    $alandminer=$row[16];
    $apersonalsafety=$row[17];
    $abirthregister=$row[18];
    $aother=$row[19];
    $tstickstone=$row[20];
    $tohthers=$row[21];
    $sbirthregister=$row[22];
    $sother=$row[23];
    $formnumber=$row[24];
    $submitdatatime=$row[25];
?>

      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $district?></td>
      <td><?php echo $unioncouncil?></td>
      <td><?php echo $village?></td>
      <td>
      <?php 
      if($rmultimedia=='true')
       {
        $rmultimedia_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rmultimedia_value = 0;
        }

        if($rgame=='true')
       {
        $rgame_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rgame_value = 0;
        }

        if($rsprort=='true')
       {
        $rsprort_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rsprort_value = 0;
        }

        if($rart=='true')
       {
        $rart_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rart_value = 0;
        }

        if($rgroupreading=='true')
       {
        $rgroupreading_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rgroupreading_value = 0;
        }

        if($rother=='true')
       {
        $rother_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $rother_value = 0;
        }

      $recreational_sum = $rmultimedia_value + $rgame_value + $rsprort_value + $rart_value + $rgroupreading_value + $rother_value;

      echo $recreational_sum;?></td>

      <td>
          <?php 
      if($alandminer=='true')
       {
        $alandminer_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $alandminer_value = 0;
        }

        if($apersonalsafety=='true')
       {
        $apersonalsafety_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $apersonalsafety_value = 0;
        }

        if($abirthregister=='true')
       {
        $abirthregister_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $abirthregister_value = 0;
        }

        if($aother=='true')
       {
        $aother_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $aother_value = 0;
        }

      $awareness_raising_sum = $alandminer_value + $apersonalsafety_value + $abirthregister_value + $aother_value;

      echo $awareness_raising_sum;?>
      </td>

      <td>
              <?php 
      if($tstickstone=='true')
       {
        $tstickstone_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $tstickstone_value = 0;
        }

        if($tohthers=='true')
       {
        $tohthers_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $tohthers_value = 0;
        }

      $training_sum = $tstickstone_value + $tohthers_value;

      echo $training_sum;?>
      </td>

      <td>
        <?php 
      if($sbirthregister=='true')
       {
        $sbirthregister_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $sbirthregister_value = 0;
        }

        if($sother=='true')
       {
        $sother_value = 1;
        }
        else{
            $sother_value = 0;
        }

      $social_mobilization_sum = $sbirthregister_value + $sother_value;

      echo $social_mobilization_sum;?>
      </td>

      <td style='color:red;'><?php echo $recreational_sum + $awareness_raising_sum + $training_sum + $social_mobilization_sum;?></td>

      </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
              </table>

");
$mpdf->Output();   exit;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very messy. The PHP code in the string is just a string not code anymore. You should write your code properly.

```
<?php
require_once 'components/app.php';
include('connection.php');
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');

$content = '
<table id="fixed_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Union Council</th>
            <th>Village</th>
            <th>Recreational</th>
            <th>Awareness Raising</th>
            <th>Training</th>
            <th>Social Mobilization</th>
            <th>Total Activities</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalDistrictUnique() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalUnionCouncilUnique() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalVillages() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalRecreational() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalAwareness() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalTraining() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . getTotalSocial() . '</b></td>
            <td style="color:red;"><b>' . (getTotalRecreational() + getTotalAwareness() + getTotalTraining() + getTotalSocial()) . '</td>
        </tr>
';

$query ='select * from general';
$run =mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $id=$row[0];
    $createdate=$row[1];
    $createday=$row[2];
    $partnername=$row[3];
    $district=$row[4];
    $unioncouncil=$row[5];
    $village=$row[6];
    $vannumber=$row[7];
    $facilitator=$row[8];
    $beneficiarytype=$row[9];
    $rmultimedia=$row[10];
    $rgame=$row[11];
    $rsprort=$row[12];
    $rart=$row[13];
    $rgroupreading=$row[14];
    $rother=$row[15];
    $alandminer=$row[16];
    $apersonalsafety=$row[17];
    $abirthregister=$row[18];
    $aother=$row[19];
    $tstickstone=$row[20];
    $tohthers=$row[21];
    $sbirthregister=$row[22];
    $sother=$row[23];
    $formnumber=$row[24];
    $submitdatatime=$row[25];

    $rmultimedia_value   = $rmultimedia == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $rgame_value         = $rgame == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $rsprort_value       = $rsprort == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $rart_value          = $rart == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $rgroupreading_value = $rgroupreading == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $rother_value        = $rother == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $recreational_sum    = $rmultimedia_value + $rgame_value + $rsprort_value + $rart_value + $rgroupreading_value + $rother_value;

    $alandminer_value      = $alandminer == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $apersonalsafety_value = $apersonalsafety == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $abirthregister_value  = $abirthregister == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $aother_value          = $aother == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $awareness_raising_sum = $alandminer_value + $apersonalsafety_value + $abirthregister_value + $aother_value;

    $tstickstone_value = $tstickstone == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $tohthers_value    = $tohthers == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $training_sum      = $tstickstone_value + $tohthers_value;

    $sbirthregister_value    = $sbirthregister == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
    $sother_value            = $sother == 'true'? 1 : 0;
    $social_mobilization_sum = $sbirthregister_value + $sother_value;

    $content .= '
    <tr>
        <td>' . $district . '</td>
        <td>' . $unioncouncil . '</td>
        <td>' . $village . '</td>
        <td>' . $recreational_sum . '</td>
        <td>' . $awareness_raising_sum . '</td>
        <td>' . $training_sum . '</td>
        <td>' . $social_mobilization_sum . '</td>
        <td style="color:red;">' . ($recreational_sum + $awareness_raising_sum + $training_sum + $social_mobilization_sum) . '</td>
    </tr>';
}

$content .= '</tbody></table>';

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);


$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write these lines:

```
<td style='color:red;'><b><?php echo getTotalDistrictUnique();?></b></td>
```

like this:

```
<td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalDistrictUnique()."</b></td>
```

Your code strucktur is build up as this one:

```
<?php 
 ...
 <?php // this is wrong, the opening PHP tag is still alive
  ... getTotalDistrictUnique()...
 ?>
?>
```

Comment: mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Comment: than you have in your `getTotalDistrictUnique()` function an `echo | print_r | var_dump | ...` (output) command. The function must **return** (not show) your datas.

Comment: Welcome always.

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation with `php` is not proper.
Please check below code and let me know if having any issue in comment box.

```
<?php 
require_once 'components/app.php';
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$html = "";
$html .= "
<table id='fixed_table' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>District</th>
        <th>Union Council</th>
        <th>Village</th>
        <th>Recreational</th>
        <th>Awareness Raising</th>
        <th>Training</th>
        <th>Social Mobilization</th>
        <th>Total Activities</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalDistrictUnique()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalUnionCouncilUnique()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalVillages()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalRecreational()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalAwareness()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalTraining()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".getTotalSocial()."</b></td>
        <td style='color:red;'><b>".(getTotalRecreational() + getTotalAwareness() + getTotalTraining() + getTotalSocial())."</td>
    </tr>";

    include('connection.php');
    $query ='select * from general';
    $run =mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $id=$row[0];
    $createdate=$row[1];
    $createday=$row[2];
    $partnername=$row[3];
    $district=$row[4];
    $unioncouncil=$row[5];
    $village=$row[6];
    $vannumber=$row[7];
    $facilitator=$row[8];
    $beneficiarytype=$row[9];
    $rmultimedia=$row[10];
    $rgame=$row[11];
    $rsprort=$row[12];
    $rart=$row[13];
    $rgroupreading=$row[14];
    $rother=$row[15];
    $alandminer=$row[16];
    $apersonalsafety=$row[17];
    $abirthregister=$row[18];
    $aother=$row[19];
    $tstickstone=$row[20];
    $tohthers=$row[21];
    $sbirthregister=$row[22];
    $sother=$row[23];
    $formnumber=$row[24];
    $submitdatatime=$row[25];

    $html .= '<tr>';

    $html .= '<td>'.$district;
    $html .= '</td>';

    $html .= '<td>'.$unioncouncil;
    $html .= '</td>';

    $html .= '<td>'.$village;
    $html .= '</td>';

    if($rmultimedia=='true')
    {
        $rmultimedia_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rmultimedia_value = 0;
    }

    if($rgame=='true')
    {
        $rgame_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rgame_value = 0;
    }

    if($rsprort=='true')
    {
        $rsprort_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rsprort_value = 0;
    }

    if($rart=='true')
    {
        $rart_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rart_value = 0;
    }

    if($rgroupreading=='true')
    {
        $rgroupreading_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rgroupreading_value = 0;
    }

    if($rother=='true')
    {
        $rother_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $rother_value = 0;
    }

    $recreational_sum = $rmultimedia_value + $rgame_value + $rsprort_value + $rart_value + $rgroupreading_value + $rother_value;

    $html .= '<td>'.$recreational_sum;
    $html .= '</td>';

    if($alandminer=='true')
    {
        $alandminer_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $alandminer_value = 0;
    }

    if($apersonalsafety=='true')
    {
        $apersonalsafety_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $apersonalsafety_value = 0;
    }

    if($abirthregister=='true')
    {
        $abirthregister_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $abirthregister_value = 0;
    }

    if($aother=='true')
    {
        $aother_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $aother_value = 0;
    }

    $awareness_raising_sum = $alandminer_value + $apersonalsafety_value + $abirthregister_value + $aother_value;

    $html .= '<td>'.$awareness_raising_sum;
    $html .= '</td>';

    if($tstickstone=='true')
    {
        $tstickstone_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $tstickstone_value = 0;
    }

    if($tohthers=='true')
    {
        $tohthers_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $tohthers_value = 0;
    }

    $training_sum = $tstickstone_value + $tohthers_value;

    $html .= '<td>'.$training_sum;
    $html .= '</td>';

    if($sbirthregister=='true')
    {
        $sbirthregister_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $sbirthregister_value = 0;
    }

    if($sother=='true')
    {
        $sother_value = 1;
    }
    else{
        $sother_value = 0;
    }

    $social_mobilization_sum = $sbirthregister_value + $sother_value;

    $html .= '<td>'.$social_mobilization_sum;
    $html .= '</td>';

    $html .= '<td style="color:red;">'.($recreational_sum + $awareness_raising_sum + $training_sum + $social_mobilization_sum);
    $html .= '</td>';

    $html .= '</tr>';
    $html .= '</tbody>';
    $html .= '</table>';

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $mpdf->Output();   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/gitconsultants/unicefnew.gitconsultants.net/file.php on line 217

Comment: I think you missing something with `php`. Debug it !